# magento 2 product custom attribute in Items Ordered Section

Tags: magento2, sales, order-grid

Please find the below requirement which i want.

I have created a product attribute **seller_demo** dropdown and assigned to a product

[image]

This attribute i need at sales order  **Items Ordered** table like

[image]

please help me how to do this.

thanks